# Proving that the index of a subgroup of $S_n$ that keeps a specific set invariant has a certain order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}, n ≥ 2$, and $k \in \{1, 2, ..., n-1\}$, and let $A \subseteq \{1, 2, ..., n\}$ with $|A| = k$. Furthermore, let $G$ be a subgroup of $S_n$ that fixes $A$, i.e. for all $π \in G$, we have that $π(A) = \{π(a): a \in A \} = A$.

I now want to show that

$(S_N:G) ≥ \pmatrix{n \\ k}$

I must admit that I haven't come very far yet. I think I must let $S_n$ operate on the set of all the subsets of $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ that have $k$ elements (of which there are $\pmatrix{n \\ k}$), so that I then can hopefully utilize the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem at some point. But I don't know how to concretely do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct. Let $S_n$ operate on the set $\binom{N}{k}$ of all $\binom{n}{k}$ possible $k$-element subsets of $N := \{1, \ldots, n\}$, and let $H$ denote the stabilizer of $A$ under this action. Since the described action is clearly transitive, we have a single orbit and therefore by the orbit-stabilizer theorem we have $|H| = |S_n|~/~|\binom{N}{k}|$. Since $G$ stabilizes $A$ too, $G$ is a subgroup of $H$, so we have $|G| \leq |H|$ and by Lagrange we get $$(S_n : G) = |S_n|~/~|G| \geq |S_n|~/~|H| = |\binom{N}{k}| = \binom{n}{k}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$S_n$ acts on all subsets of size $k$. You're thinking of $G$ as a subgroup of $F:=\text{Stab}_{S_n}(A)$.

The size of $F$ can be found using Orbit-Stabilizer.